# Solving Quadratic Inequality

Tags: inequality

I can't solve this math problem:

$$\frac{x}{2x-8} > 3 $$

To find the values of x. I have been trying for over an hour and now my head hurts!

Here is what I have done so far:

I tried:

$$ (2x-8)(2x-8)(x)/(2x-8) > 2(2x-8)(2x-8)$$
$$2x^2-8x > 3(4x^2-32x-64)$$
$$2(x^2-4x)>3*2(2x^2-16x-32$$ (divided both sides by 2) 
$$x^2-4x>3(2x^2-16x-32)$$ 
$$x^2-4x>6x^2-48x-96$$
$$0>5x^2-44x-96$$

And I can't get to the answer:

$$ 4<x<24/5$$

Can someone please help? I would be most grateful!

Comment: @RodrigoZepeda 

I don't know how to format the maths I type in this forum so I Don't know how to type out my working out to show you. How can I find out how to format my typing?

Comment: Multiply both sides with $2x-8$ and then bring the right-hand side to left giving $\ldots >0$.. Solve for $x$.

Comment: The site uses Mathjax. You can find a tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Refer this for formatting posts : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @RodrigoZepeda I tried:

$ (2x-8)(2x-8)(x)/(2x-8) > 2(2x-8)(2x-8)$
$2x^2-8x > 3(4x^2-32x-64)$
$2(x^2-4x)>3*2(2x^2-16x-32$
$x^2-4x>3(2x^2-16x-32)$  (divided both sides by 2) 
$x^2-4x>6x^2-48x-98$
$0>5x^2-52x-98$

And I can't get to the answer:

$ 4<x<24/5$

Comment: $3\times 32 = 96 \ne 98$. With that corrected, you are just one step from the answer.

Comment: You'd better double check next time first, before asking here!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for headache to solve it !

if    $   2\cdot x -8 >0  $  i.e $ x>4$
$$ x >6 \cdot x-24 $$
$$5 \cdot x<24 $$
$$x<24/5$$

so it means that $4<x<24/5$
else ($x<4$)

$$ x <6 \cdot x-24 $$
$$x>24/5$$
which means no solution as $24/5$ is greater than $4$.

In conclusion $4<x<24/5$

Answer (score 1):

If $x>4$, we have
$$x>3(2x-8)$$
$$24>5x$$
$$\frac{24}{5}>x$$
Hence
$$\frac{24}{5}>x>4$$

If $x<4$, we have
$$x<3(2x-8)$$
$$24<5x$$
Hence no solution

In conclusion, the solution is
$$\frac{24}{5}>x>4$$

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I'd do it (fill in details):

$$\frac x{2x-8}>3\iff\frac x{x-4}>6\iff \frac{x-6x+24}{x-4}>0\iff$$

$$\iff\frac{5x-24}{x-4}<0\iff(x-4)\left(x-\frac{24}5\right)<0\iff 4<x<\frac{24}5$$